# Azure Redirect from www to non-www in Angular and .Net Core API

Tags: angular, linux, azure, .net-core

I am new to Azure, but I am taking a course. However, I need to know how to set something up now.

I have an Angular 12 frontend and a .NET Core 5.0 API hosted on Azure (Linux). I want all www urls (https and non-https) to be redirected to https://example.com.

I do not have any load-sharing setup. Right now, my site is a very low-volume site. So I cannot use front door. I have tried .htaccess and web.config, and nothing seems to work.

If I type https://www.example.com, the browser will display your connection is not private. So obviously, I have something very wrong.

I do have the CNAME set to www >> example.com.

Could somebody please point me in the correct direction? I have something mucked up for sure.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling for quite a few hours, I figured out what my problem was. Oh man, the issue was right in from of my face and I was on the wrong end of the problem. I needed to add the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in custom domains in Azure. I had example.com as an assigned domain, but I did not have the www  in the assigned domains. On the bright side I did learn a lot about defining rules in .NET Core 5.0.